# Deploy a Django site and a PHP site on the same server with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I currently have a Django site working at **cinepass.com.ec** , I would like to deploy an additional PHP site to the same server at **mobile.cinepass.com.ec**

My current **httpd.conf** (from [DjangoFoo](http://www.djangofoo.com/17/django-mod_wsgi-deploy-exampl)) :

```
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/cinepass/media">
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/ec2-user/cinepass/cinepass">
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/ec2-user/cinepass/media/
ServerAdmin smansfield@palapa.com.ec
ErrorLog "logs/cinepass.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/cinepass.com-access_log" common

# mod_wsgi configuration is here
# we are running as user/group 'deamon', if you don't have those you need to change or create.
WSGIDaemonProcess cinepass python-path=/home/ec2-user/cinepass:/home/ec2-user/cinepass/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages user=daemon group=daemon processes=2 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup cinepass
# this is our WSGI file.
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/cinepass/cinepass/wsgi.py
```

My current **wsgi.py** :

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/')
sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/cinepass/')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cinepass.settings_production.py")
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

How would I edit my Apache configuration so that I can also run a php site at **mobile.cinepass.com.ec** ?

Answer (score 0):

Install and activate the PHP module. Point the DocumentRoot for the mobile site the the directory that contains your PHP files and that's it.

We run a server with several php sites and a site with Django. It was far more complicated to get Django working that it was PHP.